# Query objects has an array which has item we find

Tags: ios, core-data

Example that I have an array of many Places. In each **Place** I have a property is *sub_category* (an array).

```
sub_category": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Architecture"
    },
    {
      "id": 49,
      "name": "Family"
    },
    {
      "id": 58,
      "name": "Outdoor"
    },
    {
      "id": 69,
      "name": "People watching"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Performance"
    },
    {
      "id": 73,
      "name": "Bridge"
    }
  ],
```

All Places was saved to database. I used CoreData. Now I have a problem, how can I find places which have sub_category id = 1, 7, 73

The first solution I thought was: fetch All Places and put into in array. After that for each Place in that array. If Place have sub_category contain any sub_category_id will add to result. But I have more than 1000 places was saved. So if I fetch all places like that will take many memory. I thought that I must have a good NSPredicate and can fetch From DB with Predicate

Comment: If sub_category is an array, stored in a transformable attribute, you will not be able to fetch using a predicate based on that attribute.  If you need to do that, you should create another `Subcategory` entity (with two attributes, `id` and `name`) and establish a to-many relationship from `Place` to `Subcategory`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally solved problem. As you said if we stored in a transformable attribute we cannot use predicate based on attribute. After research and save with relationship between Subcategory and Place